# Code First Migration using Fluent API .HasIndex().HasName() is not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I am using EF 6.2. This is against an Oracle 12.1.0.2 Database.

I am able to create an index using the below code; however, when I run Update-Database and check for the index, I see that the name I provided IS NOT USED. Instead, the index appears to be named with a default naming convention of "IX_TableName_ColumnName_GUID". This becomes a problem also when I am trying to back out these changes also, because the index name provided is not used there either.

I have also tried specifying the index in Data Annotations (also shown in the code below).

Addititionally, I've tried with leaving both sections of code in place, all to no avail. I still end up with an index that is NOT named what I want.

Data Annotations

```
        [Column(TypeName = "int")]
        [Index("IXTest", 1)]
        public Int32 PARENT_ID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "int")]
        [Index("IXTest", 2)]
        public Int32 ACTION_ID { get; set; }
```

Fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PARENT_ACTION>()
                .HasIndex(e => new { e.PARENT_ID, e.ACTION_ID })
                .HasName("IXTest");
```

Here are the generated methods after running "Add-Migration IXTest"

```
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateIndex("USER.PARENT_ACTION", new[] { "PARENT_ID", "ACTION_ID" }, name: "IXTest");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropIndex("USER.PARENT_ACTION", "IXTest");
        }
```

And here is the sql logged when using the "Update-Database -Verbose" command

```
begin
  execute immediate
  'create index "USER"."IX_PARENT_ACTION_P_1329803955" on "USER"."PARENT_ACTION" ("PARENT_ID", "ACTION_ID")';
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode <> -1408 then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
```

Here is the sql logged when I target the previous migration to back out the index changes

```
begin
  execute immediate
  'drop index "USER"."IX_PARENT_ACTION_"';
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode <> -1418 then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
```

I expect that with either Fluent API or Data Annotations, the index name I specify would be used in the Update-Database command, especially since the "CreateIndex" method is called and the correct name is provided.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, it is a bug with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework. Also, it appears this bug has not been fixed, as I am using the latest release of this package: 18.3.0.

[Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.2.1100 Index Names/Migrations](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4147961)